# How do I connect an active agent with an external IP to zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, agent

Good afternoon everyone, I have a problem with the active agent connecting to the server. No problems before, but the problem appeared with 3 hosts.
Config agent:

```
PidFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
LogFileSize=0
Server=
StartAgents=0
ServerActive=zabbix.xxx.com
Hostname=azby
RefreshActiveChecks=120
UnsafeUserParameters=1
```

However, it writes an error in the logs:

```
active check configuration update from [zabbix.xxx.com:10051] started to fail (cannot connect to [[zabbix.xxx.com]:10051]: [111] Connection refused)
```

That said, in the zabbix interface itself, I'm pretty sure I wrote everything correctly.
Pings between zabbix.xxx.com and my host are going on.
Tried checking the ports:

```
[root@azby ~]# nc -zv zabbix.xxx.com 10051
nc: connect to zabbix.xxx.com port 10051 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to zabbix.xxx.com 10051 port [tcp/*] failed : Connection refused
```

And it's the same in reverse direction.
Selinux and firewall on the zabbix server are disabled.
Nothing in iptables either.
The situation is similar on 2 other machines but the error is the following:

```
active check configuration update from [127.0.0.1:10051] started to fail (cannot connect to [[127.0.0.1]:10051]: [111] Connection refused)
```

I didn't write localhost 127.0.0.1 anywhere
Please tell me, what may be the problem?

Comment: `Connection refused` `firewall on the zabbix server are disabled.`  So: 1. server is not runing. 2. Is not that ip address or dns. 3. Something else is blocking. 4. That ip is not "external" or public. 5. you have firewall for outgoing connections on zabix-agent. Etc. You go through each possible possibility and investigate. You might want to learn about `tcpdump port 10051` on server.

Comment: I check it with tcpdump.  ```[root@azby zabbix]#  sudo tcpdump -nn -i breth0 dst zabbix.xxx.com and port 10051
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on breth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
14:30:15.906537 IP 9.9.2.22.58082 > 9.9.2.22.10051: Flags [S], seq 1668302572, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:31:15.913359 IP 9.9.2.22.59154 > 9.9.2.22.10051: Flags [S], seq 1420684108, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0```

Comment: the main problem - i think so my port in zabbix server can't access